# Android MPchart Piechart Legend setCustom error

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using MPchart piechart. When i set custom legend arrays it not accepting that array.

My code...

```
Legend l = chart.getLegend();
    l.setCustom(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS, new String[] { "aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc"});
```

Error...

```
Cannot resolve method 'setCustom(int[],java.lang.String[])'
```

My MPchart version : `v3.0.0`

How can i resolve this issue.?

Comment: Wherever you found instructions to use `setCustom` like that (presumably the wiki), it's out of date. `setCustom` is now used with an array or List of `LegendEntry` objects, which contain details on how to format each entry.

The wiki should probably be updated, and there should have at least been a deprecated method in there that takes the original parameters and wraps the new implementation, but you should be able to change it on your end with no problems. Just read through the JavaDoc on LegendEntry and `setCustom` for details.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to set a custom legend:

```
 // Use Legend Entry

    LegendEntry l1=new LegendEntry("Bank", Legend.LegendForm.DEFAULT,10f,2f,null, Color.RED);
    LegendEntry l2=new LegendEntry("Chitfund", Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE,10f,2f,null, Color.GREEN);
    LegendEntry l3=new LegendEntry("Mobile", Legend.LegendForm.LINE,10f,1f,null,Color.BLACK);
    LegendEntry l4=new LegendEntry("Internet", Legend.LegendForm.DEFAULT,10f,2f,null, Color.BLUE);
    LegendEntry l5=new LegendEntry("ATM", Legend.LegendForm.DEFAULT,10f,2f,null, Color.DKGRAY);
    LegendEntry l6=new LegendEntry("Check", Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE,10f,1f,null,Color.CYAN);

    Legend l=piechart.getLegend();
    l.setCustom(new LegendEntry[]{l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6});

    //For set the same color to chart
    piedataSet.setColors(new int[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.DKGRAY, Color.CYAN});//Color is set based on your Legend entry color
```

Explanation of Legend Entry Parameters:

```
 LegendEntry l1=new LegendEntry("Bank", Legend.LegendForm.DEFAULT,10f,2f,null, Color.RED);

         Parameter                   Example
   --------------------------------------------------------

         legend label         -      "Bank"
         legend form          -      Legend.LegendForm.DEFAULT[ (DEFAULT Shape is Square) Default instead of any (like Square, circle, line)]
         formsize             -      10f,2f [height of the width]
         dashboard effect     -      null
         color                -      Color.RED
```

Answer (score 0):

working for me try this

**add color to string array**

```
String[] array;

array = new String[<**size of your color arraylist**>];
            for (int i = 0; i < **size of your color arraylist**; i++) {
                array[i] = **color arraylist**.get(i);
            }
```

**set custom color**

```
  if (array.length > 0 && array !=null) {
            l.setCustom(l.getColors(), array);
            }
```

Comment: how can i add legend names

Comment: piechart.getLegend().setEnabled(true); for brief detail see https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend