# Change combined chart legends order, MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Im using MPAndroidChart library of PhilJay to create a combined chart (line and bar). I would like to change the legend order of the plot.
From the defaul option like this:
[Default option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MXRx.png)
To this: 
[Order changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIP8y.png)

I have read the documentation and tried change the setDrwaOrder but no change happen.

¿Some help or advices?

Answer (score 0):

**setCustom(int[] colors, String[] labels):** Sets a custom legend's labels and colors arrays. The colors count should match the labels count. Each color is for the form drawn at the same index.

You need to set custom legend as follows:

```
Legend l = chart.getLegend();
l.setCustom(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS, new String[] { "Line Data", "Bar Data" });
```

In this way you can use your order for legend.
You can also give array of colors as first parameter for colors of your choice.

Comment: The solution you post is outdated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802952/android-mpchart-piechart-legend-setcustom-error But thanks to you I found this solution 


        LegendEntry l1=new LegendEntry("Bank", Legend.LegendForm.DEFAULT,10f,2f,null, Color.RED);
        LegendEntry l2=new LegendEntry("Chitfund", Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE,10f,2f,null, Color.GREEN);


        l.setCustom(new LegendEntry[]{l1,l2});


Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Android MPchart Piechart Legend setCustom error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802952/android-mpchart-piechart-legend-setcustom-error)

Using the answers to this question as a guide, I was able to figure out the following solution to my problem:

```
LegendEntry l1=new LegendEntry("Bank", Legend.LegendForm.DEFAULT,10f,2f,null, Color.RED);
LegendEntry l2=new LegendEntry("Chitfund", Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE,10f,2f,null, Color.GREEN);


l.setCustom(new LegendEntry[]{l1,l2});
```